# How to ensure rice from rice cooker becomes dry?

Tags: rice, rice-cooker, drying

I'm adding 1.5 cups of water for 1 cup of basmati rice to my rice cooker. I don't think the amount is the problem.

It's not very watery but it can feel a little watery(which probably isnt an issue for most) but I would like it very dry.

Sometimes I eat straight after its heated, could that be the issue? After it's cooked do I need to leave it open so all the water evaporates?  What can I do to ensure I get very dry rice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I normally do is fluff up the rice- sometimes its just the top layer which is a little more moist due to condensation, but if it's watery I sometimes leave the rice cooker open for a bit and let it evaporate which works for me (although I don't know if that is how you're supposed to do it)

Comment: And for those who want it *really* dry, fluff it up, but then spread it out (but don't pack it down) on a sheet pan, so there's lots of surface area for the moisture to escape from

Answer (score 1):

If you like your rice 'al dente' (very firm, but totally cooked), use a rice cooker but only half the water recommended for whatever rice you're cooking. Then cook the rice until the liquid water is gone, then continue to cook on 'warm' (most rice cookers will switch to warm automatically when the water is gone) until the full cooking time has been reached. I've done this with white rice, wild rice, wild and brown rice mixed, brown rice, black rice, and yellow (Mahatma) rice, and I've loved the results every time!

Answer (score 0):

If you want really dry, perfectly separate and elongated grains with a rice cooker, I'd suggest this method which gives me excellent results. It is a bit more work (and requires another pot), but works well with basmati/long-grain rice and any rice cooker with a steaming basket.

1. Rinse your rice either in a collander or by putting it in a saucepan and swirling/changing the water a few times
2. Leave to soak for 20 minutes
3. Bring to the boil, boil for 2 minutes, meanwhile boil a kettle of water
4. Drain, and rinse in boiled rice in cold water and allow to drain thoroughly
5. Add the boiling water from the kettle to the base of your rice cooker
6. Place the rice in the steamer section (you may need a sheet of kitchen towel to stop the rice falling through) and place in cooker
7. Steam for 15 minutes once steam emerges through the rice

The problem with many rice cookers I've come across is the way they actually cook the rice. When the rice and water are added, the combined weight pushes down on a switch and brings the water to the boil. Once the water has evaporated, the cooker goes into "keep warm" mode, which ends up with congealed rice at the bottom.

You might get better results by just soaking/rinsing the rice beforehand or adjusting the water quantity downward, but from personal experience I've never managed to get absolutely perfect rice that way. Different brands of rice will also behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

A one more solution for getting perfect dry rice. While cooking white rice put some drops of edible oil in it. It is helpful for getting perfect fluffy rice. And for better results use [World’s Longest Basmati Rice](http://tajfoods.com.au/worlds-longest-basmati-rice-2/). It's taste texture and smell is awesome.